# Can't Connect To JobHistoryServer on EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I have deployed a CDH4 cluster (MapReduce version 2, YARN) on EC2, using Whirr 0.8. The MapReduce jobs run fine and I can connect to the `NameNode` and `Resource Manager` web applications with no problems.  But I can't connect to the `JobHistoryManager` web application and I have confirmed it is running. Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Firewall issue?  You try connecting via lynx (e.g. `lynx localhost:19888`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the JobHistory Server first by executing the following command

```
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop start historyserver
```

Then go to your browser any of the following

`https://localhost:19888` OR `http://127.0.0.1:19888`

To verify if the  JobHistroy Server is running type `JPS` and you should see a list of all running services

```
2800 DataNode
12497 JobHistoryServer
3524 NodeManager
12981 Jps
2615 NameNode
3053 SecondaryNameNode
3390 ResourceManager
```